# In Symfony2, how do I get labels from the FormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

In Symfony2, I'm using formbuilder. I'm setting the labels in the form, as per the documentation.

However, when I'm on the 'show' and 'index' pages, I have to copy the labels into Twig.

Is there a way to have the same labels used everywhere? The options I have thought of:

- Access the formbuilder configuration, but without actually building the form
- Have a central config file, and lookup from the formbuilder and the twig files into that file

However, either way requires me to 'do' something, which I'm not used to in Symfony. It seems like this is something that would already have been solved, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize translation system to overcome this problem. Make sure that you have enabled translation in `config.yml`.

If you have added field in your formtype like this

```
$builder->add('title', 'text', array(
    'label'=> 'model.title'
));
//.....
```

Create a file named `messages.en.yml` in your bundles  `Resources/translations` directory (replace `en` with your default locale and create multiple files based on the locales. Check [translation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/translation.html) chapter of the book.) and put following

```
#src/YourBundle/Resources/translation/messages.en.yml
model:
    title: "Title"
    field: "Field"
    #....
```

Add and edit forms label will show `Title`. In index and show pages you can do

```
{{ "model.title" | trans([], 'messages') }}
```

Though this process is a bit lengthy but it is one time and you can change the value of the labels by changing the translation files.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the translation system for this. It also has the added advantage of quick i18n if and when it's needed. Great idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say something about @Mun Mun Das's answer.

In Symfony 6, it looks like we don't even need to use trans() anymore in the template in the form. I defined the label in the Type file (php) and it translates directly. I don't know why though.

**Example**

FormatType

```
#src/Form/UserType.php   
$builder->add('uEmail', TextType::class, array(
                    'label'=> 'uEmail' ,
                    'attr' => [ 'maxlength' => 50]
                ))
```

Translation file

```
#translations/message.en.yaml
uEmail: Email
```

It automatically translates it. I guess Symfony try to translate it by default ? If label is not set in UserType.php or in the template with *form_label()* function, it will display "u Email" by default