# How to change name value from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am still new to Symfony2. I am using Symfony version 2.3 and twig version 1.0. and I'm trying to change the name value.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    {{ form_label(form.menuTitle, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.menuTitle)}}
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="span12">
            {{ form_widget(form.menuTitle, {'attr': {'class': 'span6'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the label of a child within your form array you can do this by adding the "label" attribute in the form builder. Here's a good description: [In Symfony2, how do I get labels from the FormBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736979/in-symfony2-how-do-i-get-labels-from-the-formbuilder)

Otherwise please be a bit more specific what you mean by change "name value" ?

Comment: i want to change name="smart_contactbundle_contact[menuTitle]" to name="menuTitle". how can i do it?